# how to apply Property animation for each tab image in ViewPager

Tags: android

I'm using sliding tabs with drawable images :
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout

```
 @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        imageTabs = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
        imageTabs.setBounds(0, 0, imageTabs.getIntrinsicWidth(), imageTabs.getIntrinsicHeight());

        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(imageTabs, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return sb;
    }
```

I want to animate each tab image with property animation when tab view is shown (not on slide)
something like this (but this will not work because property animation doesn't work with drawables):

```
if(position==1)
        {
            imageTabs.animate().setDuration(300).setStartDelay(100).translate...
        }
        if(position==2)
        {
            imageTabs.animate().setDuration(300).setStartDelay(200).translate...
        }
```

How can i achive this? Thanks.

Comment: use ObjectAnimator/ValueAnimator then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a simple solution if anyone else need this.
In SlidingTabLayout java class:

```
 private void populateTabStrip() {

    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();


    int delay;
    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
           // adapter.getPageTitle(0)

        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        if (mDistributeEvenly) {
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tabView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.width = 0;
            lp.weight = 1;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);
        String desc = mContentDescriptions.get(i, null);
        if (desc != null) {
            tabView.setContentDescription(desc);
        }

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);

        }
        tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selectortab));
        //tabTitleView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selectortab));
        tabTitleView.setTextSize(14);

        delay=(i*80)+750;

        mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setScaleY(0f);
        mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setScaleX(0f);
        mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).animate()
                .setStartDelay(delay)
                .setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
                .setDuration(300)
                .scaleY(1f)
                .scaleX(1f);
    }

}
```